# Sharepoint 2013 Colour Coded Calendar Overlays

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

I am looking to change the overlay colours of a calendar in SP2013. Does anyone have a tutorial that does work?

Comment: do you mean the colors available for overlays or the color that an overlay is displayed as (ie - change a calendar that has overlaid events show as green to show as red instead)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to change the color of an existing overlay in your calendar:

1. Open the Calendar in SharePoint.
2. Open the **Calendar** menu and click **Calendars Overlay**.
3. Click the name of the calendar overlay you want to change the color for.
4. Change the Color field to whatever color you want that overlay to show as.
5. Click **OK**.

If you want to change the set of available colors available by default for overlays, you will have to do a bit more work to define custom styles. You can try referencing [this link](http://eimagine.com/how-to-change-the-default-calendar-colors-in-sharepoint/) (also read the comments on the solution).

Comment: Thanks hoffie4. I need to change the available colors. I will test it out.